# ESL connection failed to Freeswitch on remote server

Tags: c, sockets, azure, cloud, freeswitch

I have a program running on local machine which is connected successfully to freeswitch instance via ESL in my network, but when I try to connect to freeswitch instance present in cloud via ESL I get `ESL_FAIL` status. I have set listen ports in event_socket.conf to `0.0.0.0` but I am unable to connect to freeswitch in cloud. I tried using domain name for connection and I also tried to connect to freeswitch using IP of cloud machine. Any idea what could be causing this?

Password and port are correct.

Comment: try to telnet to the host/port first

Comment: Thanks for your response. I managed to connect to cloud. Seems like port was not open on cloud before.